# How can I check whether a URL or String is contained in a whitelist or a blacklist for domains, addresses e.t.c in Java?

Tags: java

I need to be able to check whether or not a given URL or web address is present in a whitelist.txt file or a blacklist.txt file, depending on how some things are configured. I'll write my question aimed at a whitelist implementation, since the code should translate easily into a blacklist.

For example, I might have a whitelist.txt file which looks similar to

```
google.com
example.net
hello.com/example
```

In my program, I will have a string containing a web address. It will be unknown at runtime how this string / web address will look. For example, it could be any of the following

```
String address1 = "http://google.com"
String address2 = "https://google.com"
String address3 = "hello.com"
```

What I need, is a way to tell whether the given strings match a domain in the whitelist.

Currently, in my program, I load the whitelist into a hashset of strings containing each address entered into the whitelist. Using the code above as an example, I would check whether the string address1 is present in the hashset. If it is, I can continue with execution. If it is not, I can display an error, saying that the address is not present in the whitelist.

This works fine, until the addresses start to differ in some way.

For example, I may want to only whitelist "https://google.com", and not "http://google.com". I might also want to only whitelist "hello.com", and not "hello.com/example". The entered address may contain "google.com", but actually be "google.comm". The cases where my current system fails goes on. As a result, doing a simple check as to whether or not an entered address is equal to what is contained in the whitelist, or a check as to whether or not the entered address contains something in the whitelist will not suffice.

I need something much more flexible, which will work with as many different formats as possible. As a side note, the addresses entered into whitelist.txt, and the addresses entered on runtime will always be strings, though processing these into an object will be fine.

Thanks if anyone can help!

Edit:
I'm currently using the String.contains method to check whether an address is present in the whitelist. I've also used String.equals(), too, however neither of these solutions fully fix my problem.

Comment: Make whitelist.txt a list of regexes? Ex: `.*\.google.com`, etc.

Comment: Could you please explain how do you currently check the similarity between the whitelist URL and address1? As an example, do you use the `String.equals()` method?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getHost--

Comment: @chameerar No, currently I am using the String.contains method. Will update my question accordingly.

Comment: @001 I'm not too sure your suggestion would be a viable solution. The whitelist is user-defined, and I'm unsure as to whether users will be all too familiar with Regex. Additionally, the code needs to be as performant as possible, since this whitelist will be checked fairly frequently. I've read that Regex can be quite intensive, but do correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @Robert Hello, thanks for your response. Do you think you could provide a little more context into how I might be able to use this in my code? Thanks!

Comment: Read the whitelist, turn the entries into `URL`s, call `getHost` on them to get the domain name. Keep those in a `Set`. Read the links or whatever you have and want to check, turn them also in `URL`s, call `getHost` again and check if it's in your `Set`. If it is, it's on the list. The `URL` class deals with parsing / understanding the URL syntax for you. (BTW, a [mcve] in your question would make it easier for me to show you the modified code.)

Comment: @JamesBayhaner to use the `java.net.URL` class as mentioned by @Robert, the URL strings should contain the protocol in them. Otherwise, creating a `URL` object without the protocol in the ULR will throw MalformedURLException. If this is valid for your case, you can go ahed with this approach.

Comment: The [URL class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) has methods to get the host, path, and other components of the URL.  One way to make a combination whitelist/blacklist is to precede the URL with a + or - sign.  This way, you can blacklist google.com and whitelist google.com/example.

Comment: @chameerar Hello there, may I ask, is there a way I can handle strings without a port given, or detect a port which should be used? Or is this already done by default? It wont really be possible to have the addressed be "www.google.com:80", for example. Sorry if I'm massively misunderstand what you're saying here, by the way!

Comment: @JamesBayhaner, to clarify you're question, you want to only save the authorities, and not the path.  You mentioned _"... only whitelist "hello.com", and not "hello.com/example"_.

Comment: Hey @Reilas, I should have clarified this. If only "hello.com" is present in the whitelist, I'd like to disallow all requests destined for "hello.com", and "hello.com/example". If only "hello.com/example" is present, I'd like to allow all requests going to "hello.com/example", but not any other paths. under that address. I feel like this may be a bit out of the way of what I really need though, so I think that will be something I'll figure out on my own. Thanks :)

Comment: @JamesBayhaner, so, would using the `String.equalsIgnoreCase` method work to meet the condition?  I don't see any other way to implement a listing.

Comment: @JamesBayhaner, you would have more than one entry, is what I'm implying.  Rather than having "google.com", you would have both the "http" and "https" as entries.

Comment: @Reilas Ideally, the whitelist would only contain "google.com", as opposed to both "https://google.com" & "http://google.com". I want to minimize the amount of entries needed in whitelist.txt as much as possible, as this will be user-defined.

Comment: @JamesBayhaner, and in the situation that they want to add "google.com/example", and "google.com" is already within the list, the new entry takes precedence?  Conversely, if they wanted to add "google.com" and "google.com/example" exists, nothing is over-written?

Comment: @JamesBayhaner, since it is user-defined, you may want to have it so they define an authority, then add schemes and paths as needed.  With the option to negate a check for a scheme, or a path, making it a _global_ match, for lack of better words.  You can do this with multiple CSV files, or even a serialized object.

Comment: @Reilas Thankyou for really getting me to think a bit more than I previously was about my system. I think my main priority for now should definitely be figuring out a way to have "google.com" apply to"h ttp://google.com", but not "google.commm", for example. Once I've done this, I'll definitely need to think further into how to handle sub paths for the authority and whatnot. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out here! p.s, I realized that my link examples are being converted into hyperlinks. I'm not sure how to fix this, so I added a space :D

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments! I'm currently trying to implement a method for doing this using java.net.URL. I will post an answer to my question with some example code if I'm able to get it working.

Comment: @JamesBayhaner what I mentioned in my previous comment was the need to have the protocol in the URL. As an example, the URL should contain `http` or `https` part to use the `java.net.URL` class. Please note that this is not related to the port as you mentioned. Refer this for more details https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.lang.String-

Comment: Hi again @chameerar. Thank you for pointing this out! I have no idea why my mind defaulted to port when you mentioned protocol, so sorry for the confusion on my end. I've been away for a couple days, but will hopefully get a little test of this feature up and running when I'm able to. Will post the code snippet in an answer for anyone who stumbles across this thread in the future. Thanks for your help, and I hope you have a nice day :)